# syncing mysql table to influxdb

Tags: mysql, database, logstash, elastic-stack, influxdb

I am trying to sync a mysql table in influxdb.
Following is my test.conf file.

```
    input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/root/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "db_endpoint"
    jdbc_user => "username"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    #parameters => { "favorite_artist" => "Beethoven" }
    #schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM table limit 10"
  }
}
output {
    stdout {codec => json_lines }
    file {
       path => "/root/response.json"
#       codec => "plain"
#       "document_id" => "%{operation_date}"
    }
}
```

For testing i am trying to store the output from mysql query in a file "response.json".
I am trying to sync the mysql table to the current file using `"document_id => "%{uid}"` but its not working and duplicate records are being stored in the file. I read the documentation and it looks like this setting is only used for elasticsearch output configuration.
how can i achieve a sync between the mysql table and records in file/influxdb?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully follow what you're trying to do. Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: @MichaelDesa, I am trying to sync mysql table data to influxdb. Are there any links or documentation for this task. I am unable to find any data regarding this topic. Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge, this would need to be a custom tool I haven't seen anyone do something like this before.